# Angular js $http service:- header is not accessible inside catch block

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I have tried different ways to access header inside catch block but was not able to achieve that .

**First try** :

```
function removePaymentAccount(currenAccountDetails) {
  var q = $q.defer();
  $http({
      url: UtilityService.createUrl(serverUrl, 'payment', 'removeMethod'),
      method: 'POST',
      data: currenAccountDetails
    }).then(function(response) {
      q.resolve(response);
    })
    .catch(function(err, status, headers) {
      console.log(headers);
      q.reject(err);
    });

  return q.promise;
}
```

Console ::

> undefined

**Second try** :

```
function removePaymentAccount(currenAccountDetails) {
  var q = $q.defer();
  $http({
      url: UtilityService.createUrl(serverUrl, 'payment', 'removeMethod'),
      method: 'POST',
      data: currenAccountDetails
    }).then(function(response) {
      q.resolve(response);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.headers('status-msg-header'));
      q.reject(err);
    });

  return q.promise;
}
```

console ::

> TypeError: err.headers is not a function
>       at payment.api.js:72
>       at processQueue (angular.js:14569)
>       at angular.js:14585
>       at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:15848)
>       at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15659)
>       at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15953)
>       at angular.js:16248
>       at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5396)
>       at angular.js:5668

**Third try:**

```
function removePaymentAccount(currenAccountDetails) {
  var q = $q.defer();
  $http({
      url: UtilityService.createUrl(serverUrl, 'payment', 'removeMethod'),
      method: 'POST',
      data: currenAccountDetails
    }).then(function(response) {
      q.resolve(response);
    })
    .catch(function(err, status, headers) {
      console.log(headers('status-msg-header'));
      q.reject(err);
    });

  return q.promise;
}
```

console::

> same as of second

**Fourth try :**

```
function removePaymentAccount(currenAccountDetails) {
  var q = $q.defer();
  $http({
      url: UtilityService.createUrl(serverUrl, 'payment', 'removeMethod'),
      method: 'POST',
      data: currenAccountDetails
    }).then(function(response) {
      q.resolve(response);
    }, function(response) {
      console.log(response.headers);
      q.reject(response);
    });

  return q.promise;
}
```

console::

> undefined

**Fifth try:**

```
function removePaymentAccount(currenAccountDetails) {
  var q = $q.defer();
  $http({
      url: UtilityService.createUrl(serverUrl, 'payment', 'removeMethod'),
      method: 'POST',
      data: currenAccountDetails
    }).then(function(response) {
      q.resolve(response);
    }, function(response, status, headers) {
      console.log(headers);
      q.reject(response);
    });

  return q.promise;
}
```

console:

> undefined

i did lots of variation but unable to access (not putting up entire list). Can anyone please help me to know what i'm missing.

Comment: did you try `finally` instead of `catch`?

Comment: not sure the .catch promise callback gets the same parameters as the error callback that you can supply to `.then`. Try using the error callback instead of the .catch promise (ie, `.then(function(){ success stuff },function(response){ error stuff here })`), check the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) doc for the actual usage syntax

Comment: @PatrickEvans i have tried that approach, let me update my question.

Comment: Have you tried just logging the first parameter: err, or response and seeing what it contains?

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes.. SyntaxError: Unexpected token R

Comment: Does the data you are trying to receive start with `R`? It might be angular is trying to auto format the response to something that it is not in the format of (ie parsing JSON when its not json text being retrieved). What is the actual response your server is giving, and any content-type headers it might put out

Comment: @PatrickEvans you are right, i have added transformResponse n it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution.

```
function removePaymentAccount(currenAccountDetails) {
  var q = $q.defer();
  $http({
      url: UtilityService.createUrl(serverUrl, 'payment', 'removeMethod'),
      method: 'POST',
      data: currenAccountDetails,
      transformResponse: function(data) {
        try {
          data = JSON.parse(data);
        } catch (e) {}
        return data;
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
      q.resolve(response);
    },function(response) {
      console.log(response.headers('status-msg-header'));
      q.reject(response);
    });

  return q.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.catch receive a response object, this object will contains the http headers.

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ha1hGCPKo0s3oEcg6JxJ?p=preview)

```
app.factory('dataService', function($http, $q){

  return {
    getPayment:function(){

       $http({
      url: 'www.google.com',
      method: 'POST',
      data: [{'name':'me'}]
      }).then(function(response) {
        $q.resolve(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        console.log(response.headers('status-msg-header'));
        console.log(response.status);
        $q.reject(response.statusText);
      });

      return $q.promise;



    }
  }

})
```